# Mini 3 Pro Legal in Mexico?

Tags: regulations, dji-mavic-mini

I'm getting confusing information regarding taking my DJI Mini 3 Pro drone to Mexico. Can anyone clarify if non citizens can fly sub 249g drones without red tape?

Comment: Did you find any information that non-citizens are allowed to fly? Any information that <250g matters? Please share the links, if any.

Comment: Nothing concrete, I ended up not taking it, just wasn't worth the risk.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal in Mexico. Government regulation says that if the drone is over 250g, it needs to be registered, but if it is under 250g it need not be registered. Otherwise, rules are pretty similar to other countries, like how it's not permitted to fly a drone near an airport (9km) or near a heliport (0.9km). Here in Mexico, we have the DJI online store and some other official distributors.

Here is the link to government official documentation for a more complete explanation:  (is in Spanish)

https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/attachment/file/602732/nom-107-sct3-2019-201119.pdf

Regards